# Sailsjs view caching (bug ?)

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js, ejs

I was rendering a `view` using `res.view('layout', {my: 'Object'})`.

**Peculiar Behaviour:**

When I changed the `ejs` file and refreshed the browser, the change was visible (without server restart).

BUT

If my object contained a `truthy` value of property `cache`, like so:

> `res.view('layout', {my: 'Object', cache: true})`

then, I open the `view` in the browser, all's good. But if I change the `ejs` file now, the changes do not show in the browser on refresh, unless server is stopped and re-lifted.

Is there any documentation of `sailsjs` about this that I missed, or is this part of `express` framework or `ejs` or is it a bug ?

```
SailsJs v0.10.5
NodeJs v0.10.33
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are activating `ejs` caching by setting the `cache` option to `true`.  This is an unfortunate side effect of `ejs` mixing its view locals and options together.  If your intention was to have a view local named `cache`, you'll have to name it `_cache` or something.  See the [ejs docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs#options) for a list of all possible options.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This happens even while using `dust` templates. Would you, by any chance, know why that happens ?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it was the same reason with the same solution.

Comment: this question is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36204210/sailsjs-generate-dynamic-views-ejs-files/36269639 @sgress454 any hint?