# sailsjs generate dynamic views/ejs files

Tags: sails.js, ejs

I'm generating/copying ejs files dynamically and put them in views folder and they work fine in development mode however in production mode it's not reflecting changes until I relaunch sails. How can I make it work in production mode as well?

I'm using simple fs create/update file operations to write to ejs file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. Following posts helped me in that:

[Sailsjs view caching (bug ?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28294429/sailsjs-view-caching-bug?rq=1)

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/3513

http://expressjs.com/en/api.html

The reason is, express was cashing views in production mode, so on disabling that it worked.

```
sails.hooks.http.app.disable('view cache');
console.log("view-cache-disabled: " + sails.hooks.http.app.disabled("view cache"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a watcher like forever, nodemon, or something else...

Install forever by running:

```
sudo npm install -g forever
```

Run it:

```
forever -w start app.js
```